# FindFit as a function

Tags: fitting

I know for Fit one can use e.g.

```
data = Table[x^2, {x, 1, 10}]

(* ==> {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100} *)

f[x_] = Fit[data, {1, x}, x]
```

the result is a function. What is the corresponding code for FindFit? I get an error when trying a similar thing there.

Edit: actually I get the error

```
"Tag Plus in (18.4685 -63.5287\ x+49.1388\ \
x^2)\[InvisibleApplication](x_) is Protected."
```

**EDIT2: Actually it works it's just that I had previous definition messing things up. So there is no problem here, I can close or delete this if you wish.**

Answer (score 2):

Well, this:

```
f[x_] := a x + b
g[x_] := g[x] = f[x] /. FindFit[data, f[x], {a, b}, x]
g[x]
```

> -22. + 11. x

The memoization should be used in order not to fit repeatedly every time `g[x]` is called.

Comment: Every time you evaluate `g[x]` it will be fitting again and again?

Comment: Previous definitions messed things up, see edit.

Comment: @BlacKow Good point, should be `g[x_]:=g[x]=...` I think.

Comment: @corey979 you probably want to edit your answer to include memoization